Schema validation failed in Realm/Atlas due to an unknown type
I have a Kotlin Multiplatform app that I'm trying to get to work with Realm/Atlas. When I try to do a Realm.open(it) it says:

IllegalStateException@29576} "java.lang.IllegalStateException:
[RLM_ERR_SCHEMA_VALIDATION_FAILED]: Schema validation failed due to
the following errors: Property 'PelletInsertionVisit.pelletMapAsList'
of type 'array' has unknown object type 'PelletToNumberUsedMapEntry'

I have multiple classes but the ones germane to this are the following:
class PelletInsertionVisit : RealmObject {
@PrimaryKey
var _id: String = ""
var visitDate = LocalDateTime.now().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)
var pelletsUsed: RealmList<Pellet> = realmListOf()
var pelletMapAsList: RealmList<PelletToNumberUsedMapEntry> = realmListOf() //Maps pellet name to number of pellets of that type used

var signedInUser: String = "UNKNOWN" //User name of user performing the update


override fun toString(): String {
    return "PelletInsertionVisit(visitDate=$visitDate, pelletsUsed=$pelletsUsed, pelletMap=$pelletMapAsList, signedInUserUserName='$signedInUser')"
}

}

And this one:
class PelletToNumberUsedMapEntry : EmbeddedRealmObject {
var pelletKey: String = "NOTSET"
var numberUsed: Int = 0
}

Right before I call the Realm.open(it) I execute this code:
    private fun setupRealmSync() {
    val user = runBlocking { appServiceInstance.currentUser }
    val config = user?.let {
        SyncConfiguration
            .Builder(
                it,
                setOf(UserAccount::class,Pellet::class, PelletInsertionVisit::class, PelletLot::class, Patient::class,
                    Practice::class )
            )
            .initialSubscriptions(rerunOnOpen = true) { realms ->
                add(
                    realms.query<PelletInsertionVisit>(),
                    name = "Pellet Insertion Visit info",   
                    updateExisting = true
                )

                add(realms.query<PelletLot>(), name = "Pellet info", updateExisting = true)
                add(realms.query<Patient>(), name = "Patient info", updateExisting = true)
                add(realms.query<Practice>(), name = "Practice info", updateExisting = true)
                add(realms.query<UserAccount>(), name = "UserAccount info", updateExisting = true)
            }
            .build()
    }

So, PelletInsertionVisit is added (and I see it in MongoDB Compass), but it's not liking the other class. I thought that it being embedded would suffice, but is that the issue?

Your code actually looks fine and the classes are set up correctly. I think the error is indicating the compiler cannot find the PelletToNumberUsedMapEntry embedded class definition. Perhaps the file is not being seen or not part of the project.

Can you share more information around this? Are you generating the Schema from Mongo Console, you can check in the Device-Sync/Sync Models, and match whether each field's data type is exact same as it is shown in the Sync-Models alternatively you can enable the Development mode so that the models that is in your device will be synced in the cloud and then if anything brakes from Backend services then you can debug that side, we have been working on Realm since last month, and have overcome such scenarios where our sync gets broke, so feel free to contact, I will be happy to help.
